# SQL cross join with partial table

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sql-insert, cross-join

I am struggling to get the following SQL query to work:

```
sql_query = f'''
    INSERT INTO table3(animal_id, fruit_id)
    SELECT table1.id, table2.id
    FROM table1
    CROSS JOIN table2
    WHERE table2.id = "{some_value}";
'''
```

### Basically I want to append to table3 the cross join of some columns from table 1 and table 2, but to limit the joined values from table 2 to those rows where table2.id equals some spefic value.  Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

EDIT:
so say you had the following three tables:

```
1
ID ANIMAL
  1    Cat
  2    Dog
```

```
2
ID  FRUIT
  1  apple
  2 orange
  3 banana
```

```
3
ID ANIMAL  FRUIT
  1   Bird mango
  2   Bird grape
```

How can I make it that I cross join the animal and fruit columns of tables 1 and 2 and append the result to table 3 but only for those rows of table 1 which equal the value specified in the curly brackets, e.g. here 'Dog'

```
3
ID ANIMAL   FRUIT
  1   Bird  mango
  2   Bird  grape
  3    Dog  apple
  4    Dog orange
  5    Dog banana
```

Comment: Your question is not 100% clear to me. Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: Include information (in the question) to show and explain what you don't like about the result (error, wrong results, etc).  Depending on the underlying database, the following expression can cause an error `"{some_value}"`, because double quotes (in standard SQL and many databases) refer to identifiers (like column and table names).  Your literal is probably not a valid column reference.  Use single quotes (for literals) instead, to be more compatible with most databases and the standard.

Comment: @The Impaler I have updated my question

Comment: Tag the question with the specific database (PostgreSQL, SQL Server, MySQL, etc) you are using.

Comment: @JonArmstrong I think that may have solved it actually

Comment: Yes. PostgreSQL uses standard double quotes to represent an object reference, not a literal value.  Use single quotes for literals which require quoting.

Comment: Remember, 'Dog' isn't the `id`.  You either want the actual id in `{some_value}` or use `table1.animal = '{some_value}'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should work if you use single instead of double quotes for the parameter that you pass, but you don't need the `CROSS` join if you are sure that `table2` contains that parameter .
You can simplify the code to:

```
INSERT INTO table3 (ANIMAL, FRUIT) 
SELECT ANIMAL, 'Dog'
FROM table1;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4374e5dcc9f5461f5262fd13ae8d9a65).